# Protection High side Mosfet driver with less solenoid connection

Tags: mosfet, solenoid, inductive

I suggest control solenoid. Solenoid will be connected externally via a connector. Steering is via high side MOSFET driver. The requirements are for detecting disconnection, short circuit and current detection. I use the circuit from TI TPS1H100BQ1.
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/tps1h100-q1-558214.pdf

When on switch mode I am disconnecting solenoid induced voltage will destroy the Mosfet. I'm confused with the protection of the mosfet when disconnecting one side of the solenoid. Do you have any advice?

My circuit:
[image: My circuit:]

Comment: In the above circuit, an inductive load, such as a solenoid, can generate a negative voltage (Out+ relative to Out-) when the switch goes off. There is already a D2 to limit the negative voltage.

Comment: The problem occurs when the mosfet is turned on and one wire inductive loads are disconnected. Then neither diode D2 not rescued mosfet .

Comment: Now I understand the situation better, unfortunately I don't have a definite idea of what is causing the failure. Imagine the connector is being disconnect, when the contacts break, the negative voltage ramps up. The contacts might close again or there might be sparks, and the big negative voltage is applied. D2 is still supposed to shunt the negative voltage, but for some reason may not be effective due to the sharp step. Perhaps try to put another fast diode of at least a few amps rating directly under the connector pins (or better yet put it with the solenoid if that is an option).